# How big a sample size do I need to confidently calculate if my "False Negative Rate" has changed over time?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, statistical-power

## Problem

I have a classification model, and I would like to know if the distribution of its predictions stay stable over time (e.g. the False Negative Rate).

## The model

The model is a binary classifier that was trained by someone else, so I will not go into details with real-world numbers here, but instead make an equivalent example.

On the test dataset of 1001 samples the model did the following predictions:

|  | Healthy | Sick |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Class 1 | 3 | 98 |
| Class 2 | 898 | 2 |

This would give us a False Negative Rate of 2/(98+2)=2%.

## Production

In production we no longer have labels on the samples that we make predictions on. The first month of production, I make predictions on 2000 data points, and I get the following distribution of my predictions:

|  | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Class 1 | 200 |
| Class 2 | 1800 |

## Question

Now I would like to know if my False Negative Rate is also around 2 % here, so I take a sample and send it to manual labeling.

1. How big should that sample be?
2. Which statistical test should I use to test is the False Negative Rate is 2 % in that sample?
3. How certain would I be that the False Negative Rate is 2 %?

## My thoughts

I suspect that I will need to do some kind of **power calculation** for some **statistical test**. But I am not confident which is the appropriate **statistical test** to use, and I have only considered the **Kolmogorov–Smirnov test**? Also, when working with a binary classifier how should I define the inputs for the **power calculation** such as **effect size**, **variability** and **significance level**. Finally, is there some efficient way to limit the number of samples that I need to send to manual labeling e.g. by oversampling **class 1**?

Comment: Hej Esben, are you sure you only have 4 out of 2000 classified as class 1? When the false negative rate is 2%, that would amount to 0.08 healthy individuals, if I understand it right.

Comment: I am pretty new to all this, so I am not 100 % sure. But isn't the "False negative rate" calculated as "Number of False Negatives" divided by "All Positives", which would be 2/(2+98)? For the unlabeled data we don't have this rate, be we would like to confidently estimating it using a sampling strategy.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood "false negative rate" the same way as you do - I think you are right. Could you change table 1 such that one of the "2"s there becomes a "3"? Then it would be unambiguous :-)

Comment: I have now changed one of the 2s to make it unambiguous :)

Comment: Good! So your classifier predicted that only 4 out of 2000 are sick (class 1), while in the training data, there were 101 out of 1100 classified as sick? That is a huge difference: if the situation in production was the same as in training, you would expect about 200, not 4 in class 1.

Comment: Ha ha, sorry my example is messed up. I will just fix it. It was supposed to predict that 10 % are sick and 90 % healthy, and I made it wrong in the second case.

Comment: Is your goal mainly to say something about the population, or about the validity of your model? // What is the model based upon? Many explanatory variables? Do you still have the training data used for fitting the model? A change in prediction quality could be due to different composition of your population as compared to the training set.

Comment: I want to say something about the validity of my model over time. If the model's False Negative Rate goes up over time, then it is not robust, and does not live up to the company's risk willingness.